# Overriding remote git repository with my repository

Tags: git

The remote repository contains a bad version. I have the copy of a good version locally. I want to replace everything that's on the remote repository with my current repository (the remote repository has a few more commits (including a merge) that should not have happened).

If I try to push, it tells me I need to pull first, but I don't want to do that, because that would mess my local version. I want the remote repo to contain what I have locally.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force "git push" to overwrite remote files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-push-to-overwrite-remote-files)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use the `--force`, Luke.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html

Comment: Same thing: `! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)`

Comment: Then you need to turn off `receive.denyNonFastForwards` in the remote's repository .git/config, if it's refusing it even with `--force` specified.

Comment: Used `git config receive.denyNonFastForwards false` on the remote repo and I have the same error.

Comment: @Amber, I'm running `git push -f origin master` on the local repo.

Comment: Huh. Um, I guess you could try going the other way, using `git fetch` from the remote repo to pluck the good version out of your local?

Comment: That should have overwritten master on the remote then, and thus the remote should now be pointing at the good version.

Comment: I tried `git push origin some_branch --force` but it always returned Everything is up-to-date message. But, `git push origin your_branch:some_branch --force` and this was what I was missing. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a new local branch from your known good version
2. Pull
3. Switch to the known bad branch
4. Fully merge your known good branch into the known bad branch
5. Commit and push

I usually use a process like this to preserve exactly what changed, have an isolated branch that's a known good copy, etc. It's probably excessive compared to using --force, but I prefer it.

Comment: The `merge` doesn't work, because the good changes are older than the bad changes, so nothing to merge.