# Force "git push" to overwrite remote files

Tags: git, git-push

I want to push my local files, and have them on a remote repo, without having to deal with merge conflicts. I just want my local version to have priority over the remote one.

How can I do this with Git?

Comment: Did `git push origin --force` not work for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding remote git repository with my repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310208/overriding-remote-git-repository-with-my-repository)

Comment: It's unclear if you only want to override the .git files, or the associated working copy.
If it's the git repository, git push is the answer. If you want to update the remote working copy, you have to use a post-receive hook

Comment: A likely cause, force push does not work is, that it may have been explicitly disabled on the remote repo (to ensure nothing get losts due to idiotic and/or malign contributors): use `config receive.denyNonFastforwards` to find out.

Comment: I tried `git push origin some_branch --force` but it always returned Everything is up-to-date message. But, `git push origin your_branch:some_branch --force` and this was what I was missing. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1468, accepted):

You should be able to force your local revision to the remote repo by using

```
git push -f <remote> <branch>
```

(e.g. `git push -f origin master`). Leaving off `<remote>` and `<branch>` will force push all local branches that have set `--set-upstream`.

Just be warned, if other people are sharing this repository their revision history will conflict with the new one. And if they have any local commits after the point of change they will become invalid.

**Update**: Thought I would add a side-note. If you are creating changes that others will review, then it's not uncommon to create a branch with those changes and rebase periodically to keep them up-to-date with the main development branch. Just let other developers know this will happen periodically so they'll know what to expect.

**Update 2**: Because of the increasing number of viewers I'd like to add some additional information on what to do when your `upstream` does experience a force push.

Say I've cloned your repo and have added a few commits like so:

```
            D----E  topic
           /
A----B----C         development
```

But later the `development` branch is hit with a `rebase`, which will cause me to receive an error like so when I run `git pull`:

```
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From <repo-location>
 * branch            development     -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging <files>
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in <locations>
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Here I could fix the conflicts and `commit`, but that would leave me with a really ugly commit history:

```
       C----D----E----F    topic
      /              /
A----B--------------C'  development
```

It might look enticing to use `git pull --force` but be careful because that'll leave you with stranded commits:

```
            D----E   topic

A----B----C'         development
```

So probably the best option is to do a `git pull --rebase`. This will require me to resolve any conflicts like before, but for each step instead of committing I'll use `git rebase --continue`. In the end the commit history will look much better:

```
            D'---E'  topic
           /
A----B----C'         development
```

**Update 3:** You can also use the `--force-with-lease` option as a "safer" force
push, [as mentioned by Cupcake in his
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24768381/456814):

> Force pushing with a "lease" allows the force push to fail if there
>   are new commits on the remote that you didn't expect (technically, if
>   you haven't fetched them into your remote-tracking branch yet), which
>   is useful if you don't want to accidentally overwrite someone else's
>   commits that you didn't even know about yet, and you just want to
>   overwrite your own:
>
> ```
> git push <remote> <branch> --force-with-lease
> ```
>
> You can learn more details about how to use `--force-with-lease` by
>   reading any of the following:
>
> - [`git push` documentation](http://jk.gs/git-push.html)
> - [Git: How to ignore fast forward and revert origin [branch] to earlier commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166713/git-how-to-ignore-fast-forward-and-revert-origin-branch-to-earlier-commit/18505634#18505634)

Comment: Since this is the selected answer, I will comment here. Using force isn't a problem when working by yourself. For example, my cloud host starts with it's own git. If I work locally and build a project, and I want to put it on my cloud host (OpenShift), I have two separate git projects. My local and my OpenShift one. I get my local just as I like, but now want to preview it on my OpenShift. You then push to OpenShift for the first time, using `-f` flag. Essentially putting your local git onto OpenShift.

Comment: You can also do `git push -f` as long as the remote branch you want to push to is the most recent one you pushed to.

Comment: "will force push all local branches" - Why would it push anything but the active branch?

Comment: I tried `git push origin some_branch --force` but it always returned Everything is up-to-date message. But, `git push origin your_branch:some_branch --force` and this was what I was missing. Hope it helps!

Comment: I had the same issue, however currently I am getting this message (github specific):

```remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
```

Answer (score 162):

### You want to force push

What you basically want to do is to force push your local branch, in order to overwrite the remote one.

If you want a more detailed explanation of each of the following commands, then see my details section below. You basically have 4 different options for force pushing with Git:

```bash
git push <remote> <branch> -f
git push origin master -f # Example

git push <remote> -f
git push origin -f # Example

git push -f

git push <remote> <branch> --force-with-lease
```

If you want a more detailed explanation of each command, then see my long answers section below.

**Warning:** force pushing will overwrite the remote branch with the state of the branch that you're pushing. Make sure that this is what you really want to do before you use it, otherwise you may overwrite commits that you actually want to keep.

## Force pushing details

#### Specifying the remote and branch

You can completely specify specific branches and a remote. The `-f` flag is the short version of `--force`

```
git push <remote> <branch> --force
git push <remote> <branch> -f
```

#### Omitting the branch

When the branch is omitted, Git will figure it out based on your config settings. In Git versions after 2.0, a new repo will have default settings to push the currently checked-out branch:

```
git push <remote> --force
```

while prior to 2.0, new repos will have default settings to push multiple local branches. The settings in question are the `remote.<remote>.push` and `push.default` settings (see below).

#### Omitting the remote and the branch

When both the remote and the branch are omitted, the behavior of just `git push --force` is determined by your `push.default` Git config settings:

```
git push --force
```

- As of Git 2.0, the default setting, `simple`, will basically just push your current branch to its upstream remote counter-part. The remote is determined by the branch's `branch.<remote>.remote` setting, and defaults to the origin repo otherwise.
- Before Git version 2.0, the default setting, `matching`, basically just pushes all of your local branches to branches with the same name on the remote (which defaults to origin).

You can read more `push.default` settings by reading `git help config` or [an online version of the git-config(1) Manual Page](http://jk.gs/git-config.html).

#### Force pushing more safely with `--force-with-lease`

Force pushing with a "lease" allows the force push to fail if there are new commits on the remote that you didn't expect (technically, if you haven't fetched them into your remote-tracking branch yet), which is useful if you don't want to accidentally overwrite someone else's commits that you didn't even know about yet, and you just want to overwrite your own:

```
git push <remote> <branch> --force-with-lease
```

You can learn more details about how to use `--force-with-lease` by reading any of the following:

- [`git push` documentation](http://jk.gs/git-push.html)
- [Git: How to ignore fast forward and revert origin [branch] to earlier commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166713/git-how-to-ignore-fast-forward-and-revert-origin-branch-to-earlier-commit/18505634#18505634)

Comment: You're right, but this should really only be used in **exceptional** situations.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets "*I would prefer is to push what I have and let it overwrite remotely rather than integrate.*" I gave the OP exactly what he asked for.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768330/git-push-is-rejected-but-i-dont-want-to-integrate

Answer (score 37):

Another option (to avoid any forced push which can be problematic for other contributors) is to:

- put your new commits in a dedicated branch
- reset your `master` on `origin/master`
- merge your dedicated branch to `master`, always keeping commits from the dedicated branch (meaning creating new revisions on top of `master` which will mirror your dedicated branch).
  See "[git command for making one branch like another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267)" for strategies to simulate a `git merge --strategy=theirs`.

That way, you can push master to remote without having to force anything.

Comment: How does the result differ from "push -force"?

Comment: @alexkovelsky Any forced push would rewrite the history, forcing other users of the repo to reset their own local repo to match the newly pushed commits. This approach only creates new commits and does not require a forced push.

Answer (score 23):

Works for me:

```
git push --set-upstream <remote> <branch> -f
```

Answer (score 14):

`git push -f` is a bit destructive because it resets any remote changes that had been made by anyone else on the team. A safer option is

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

What `--force-with-lease` does is refuse to update a branch unless it is the state that we expect; i.e. nobody has updated the branch upstream. In practice this works by checking that the upstream ref is what we expect, because refs are hashes, and implicitly encode the chain of parents into their value.

You can tell `--force-with-lease` exactly what to check for, but by default will check the current remote ref. What this means in practice is that when Alice updates her branch and pushes it up to the remote repository, the ref pointing head of the branch will be updated. Now, unless Bob does a pull from the remote, his local reference to the remote will be out of date. When he goes to push using `--force-with-lease`, git will check the local ref against the new remote and refuse to force the push. `--force-with-lease` effectively only allows you to force-push if no-one else has pushed changes up to the remote in the interim. It's `--force` with the seatbelt on.

Answer (score 5):

```
// make sure your local branch is up to date
git checkout fix-build
git pull origin fix-build

// push your local branch to overwrite remote branch 'main'
git push -f origin fix-build:main
```

ps. The accepted answer did not work for me. I am not sure if it is due to Git version.