# error: hook declined to update refs/heads/external_pub while pushing a branch

Tags: git

Currently, I'm working on 'external_pub' branch. I made few changes in one file, added it, committed & then tried to push:

```
git push origin external_pub
```

But this was resulted into an error:

```
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/external_pub
To ssh://XXX/testing.git
! [remote rejected] external_pub -> external_pub (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://XXX/testing.git'
```

Then I tried to push branch without any change to see what happens(just for isolating issue). I did following:

```
git reset --hard <commit_id> (to reset to last working sha commit)
git status
```

Above command showed:

```
# On branch external_pub
# Your branch is ahead of 'development' by 5 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Then

```
git pull origin external_pub
```

It showed: your branch is already upto date

Then

```
git push origin external_pub
```

This time also, it showed the same error as above. Could you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

There's a [git hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on the server that rejected the push. Quoting:

> These scripts run before and after pushes to the server. The pre hooks
>   can exit non-zero at any time to reject the push as well as print an
>   error message back to the client; you can set up a push policy that’s
>   as complex as you wish.

To find out why, you need to know what the hook does. Hooks are stored in `hooks` folder inside the git folder (on the remote end) - find the **pre-receive** hook or **update** hook and examine that.

Comment: In my .git/hooks folder, there is no pre-receive.sample, I've post-receive.sample

Comment: It should be on the remote, not on your local repo.

Answer (score 0):

In OSX its usually caused by missing GEM's between brew ruby install and Apple ruby 2.0 (default).

An include 'require json/ext/parser' or similar add-on is not found and exceptions at the require point.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. Normally I use VSTSID (Visual Studio Team Services) in message while committing code. Use the steps below:

1. git commit --amend (now its time to edit your commit message)
2. git commit -m "vs[your_vsts_id]-your_commit_message>"
   then press
3. i(keyboard button)
4. Esc(keyboard button)
5. :wq(to save)

After that you will be able to push(git push).

If you still facing the issue, type `git reset --soft HEAD^` in git bash. Now you can see all your files in green color. It means, files are  again ready for commit. Depending on your requirement, you can use reset (`git reset`) command as well.

Comment: to reset use
git reset HEAD~
https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2017/09/19/revert-file-after-commit/

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using **[Redmine Git Hosting](http://redmine-git-hosting.io/)**, check your projet permissions **Manager** role has been assigned to the user that is trying to rewrite his/her git's tracking references.

Please note that I am assuming you are aware on **git push -force** impact on the other users that may be sharing the same remote branch. For further details, [check this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10510482/378115)