# ASP.NET Service.exe isn't picked up by GitHub

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, service, github

I'm using the GitHub application for windows to transfer my code between my local and the server. I've made two ASP.net services thus far, which work fine- however my latest c# service's .exe and related files aren't picked up by the GitHub app, meaning when I pull from the server, the .exe of the service isn't available to allow installation. (From the debug folder, the installation.log file is picked up, but not the .exe and some attached .dlls)

I've reviewed the directory, and there's no git.ignore instructing the app to ignore it.
Furthermore, when I make changes to my existing services, their .exe is updated, and picked up by the app and allowed to transfer.

Why doesn't my new service's .exe and related installation files get picked up?

I'm using VS2008 (Don't judge me, it's comfortable).

Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly adding and committing it to git?

Comment: Nikhil, I haven't yet. I've also just noticed that in my /Debug folder, it's also skipping over my .dll files from other projects, and various service related files- literally the only files being picked up are InstallLog, and InstallState- which are 2 of the 17 files in the /Debug folder...

Comment: With a normal hard disk, VS2008 starts a lot faster than VS2010 or later. So I like VS2008 if the project is simple enough.

Comment: I know you mentioned it, but could you double check the existence of as .gitignore file anywhere in your project. The behavior you mentioned is typical of that file.

Comment: @Nikhil - There's a .gitignore at the root of my solution project, but the contents don't seem to be specific to my service- and if it were general, it would apply to the other services too, yet they function as intended.
For what it's worth, the contents of the .gitignore:
*.user
*.suo
*.pdb
obj/
/WebClient.Business/bin/Debug/WebClient.Data.dll
/WebClient.Business/bin/Debug/WebClient.Business.dll
/WebClient.Data/bin/Debug/WebClient.Data.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey actually something like that happened to me once with the Github for Windows. Well at least for what I understand is that the file doesn't get added to the remote git repo.

I would start the git shell:

`Open the repo you're working on >> Tools and Options (Button) >> Open a shell here`

There try this to see if file is added to the repo:

`git ls-files yourService.exe --error-unmatch`

if not try figuring out if it's ignored some how:

`git check-ignore -v -- yourService.exe`

if you get nothing, it's not ignored. If you do get output it is ignored somehow.

So first if it's ignored force add it manually:

`git add -f yourService.exe`

Now commit and push it to the server. In case you've never done this manually use:

`git commit yourService.exe "This is a commit message for one file only..."` (For commiting on a specific file)

or if you want to commit on all changes and added files use:

`git commit -a yourService.exe "This is a commit message for all changes and added files..."`

In the case it's not even ignored you may have merge problems with the server, in that case you have to to force push to server by using: `git push -f <remote> <branch>` (e.g. `git push -f origin master`) which is very well explained by Trev Norris here: [Force "git push" to overwrite remote files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-to-overwrite-remote-files-on-push).

After that it should be solved, I kinda stopped using Github for Windows because of these ignore issues (which might be purposely developed but I do it manually and use www.github.com for visuals).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi CMPSoares- thanks for the depth in your answer. I'll give it a whirl soon and let you know how it went.

Comment: Hope it works, I prefer using the command-line git tools instead of GUI applications because you can see exactly what's happening, Github for Windows hides certain options when committing or what they call "sincronizing" which is an automated mixture of push, pull and merge commands.

Well let me now, and if not try giving more detail so that we can help more.

Comment: Terribly sorry for the delay. It's worked for me- not sure if directly, but indirectly for sure. I'll mark it for you.