# Git push is rejected but I don't want to integrate

Tags: git, github

I performed a git push on a local project and got the message below:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/jongravois/arman.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

The note explains how to integrate by using git pull but what I would prefer is to push what I have and let it overwrite remotely rather than integrate.

Is there a command for that?