# Replace remote master branch with my local

Tags: git, github

I've been working on a project and things got sloppy.  I've `reset` to a stable commit, but when I try to `push` I'm told "the current branch is behind its remote counterpart" (obviously).  The only option that Git gives me to perform is `git pull`.  When I try that I'm back to the newer, sloppy commits that don't work and I don't want.

I made a different branch called `stable` and ran `reset --hard` to the stable commit and then tried the following:

```
$ git checkout stable
  # =>  Switched to branch 'stable'

$ git merge -s ours master
  # =>  Already up-to-date.

$ git checkout master
  # =>  Switched to branch 'master'
  # =>  Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 9 commits, and can be fast-forwarded (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

$ git merge stable
  # => Already up-to-date.
```

After running these commands my `master` branch is still in the state that I want to get rid of.

I'd like to have `stable` be the new `master` but am unsure what to do now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force "git push" to overwrite remote files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-push-to-overwrite-remote-files)

Comment: Ah, I agree; I did not see that in my searches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for a force push (see the [`--force`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) option). Just have a care with that as you probably do not normally want to change the history of a remote branch shared with other developers.

Comment: Ahhhh *facepalm*.  Thank you, thank you.  I'm aware that this is not a good practice, but it's a small personal project and I'm a bit rusty :)