# How do I delete a commit from git history as if it was not at all there?

Tags: git, github

My scenario is like this:

A->B->C->D

A was the original version of code I received(it had commits before it, but not mentioning it here).

In B, I applied code formatting which introduced hundreds of whitespace changes. Hence the person reviewing the code found over thousands of changes due to it. While I know that adding ?w=1 parameter to the commit url on github allows code diffs without whitespaces, the reviewer is not accepting that and tells me to simply revert to previous formatting. I think the only way to deal with this scenario is to simply delete C and D from history(locally and remotely) and then make the changes again.

I tried git revert but that seems to temporarily delete changes in remote. After next git push, it pushes the commits AGAIN.

Please suggest proper steps so that C,D totally gets deleted from history both locally and remotely as if they were never there(thereby rewriting history).

Note:

I am on MASTER branch and my local repo is totally in sync with remote.

**EDIT**:

I have ALREADY TRIED that accepted answer in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git). Here is what I did:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Then I did `git push origin HEAD --force`

But I get this command:

```
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: HEAD
```

And if i put `master` instead of HEAD, i get "everything up to date".

I am pushing to master and I have just one working branch at this moment.

Comment: "deleted from history both locally and remotely" You cannot change history on the remote repo.

Comment: @matt then is there no way to remove C,D totally? I simply don't want my manager having to compare so many whitespace changes when he sees the diff at D with B(as I made 2 commits since he last reviewed).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete commits from a branch in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git)

Comment: @AndrewC I have already tried that answer. Infact I have tried ALL answers on first page of google search for "Delete commit from history git" on stackoverflow.

Comment: @AndrewC and that link in your answer is THE MOST viewed topic on this issue. So its highly unlikely that I would have missed that before posting it here.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-push-to-overwrite-remote-files  without knowing what your local and tracking branch is would be guessing.

Comment: @AndrewC pls read carefully: "I am pushing to master and I have just one working branch at this moment."

Comment: I am reading carefully.  You say you are getting "unqualified destination" which usually means your branch tracking is screwed up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77439/discussion-between-rahulserver-and-andrew-c).

Answer (score 3):

If you have pushed C and D to the remote and other people have picked them up, there's not a lot you can do without running a chance of making a big mess. Your best bet is to start with `git revert D`. This will make a new revision, D', which looks identical to the state that C was in. Both D and D' will still be in the git history though.

Then you can `git revert C` and finally `git revert B` if that is your desire. Then your history will look like A-B-C-D-D'-C'-B' and checking out B' will give you code identical to checking out A.

Or you could tell the reviewer to suck it up and deal because all of this is a major pain in the ***.

Comment: yes its indeed major pain in the ***. but I can't make him suck it up as I have to keep my job. Would try your solution though as it sounds more logical.

Comment: I would do all the reverts locally and test the results thoroughly before pushing!

Comment: I am the only person using that repo at this moment. so no issues even if we rewrite the history.

Answer (score 1):

> `A---B---C---D        master`
>
> In B, I applied code formatting which introduced hundreds of whitespace changes
>
> the reviewer is not accepting that and tells me to revert to previous formatting

---

> I think the only way to deal with this scenario is to simply delete C and D from history

If I'm reading this correctly and the quotes at the top here are the payload, then what you want is the history you'd have if you'd never done `B`.  That's what `git rebase` is for.

```
git rebase --onto $A $B master
```

is the full spelling.  It says "take the master branch commits since `$B` and apply all the changes in each onto `$A`, then move the `master` label to the new series.  This will produce

```
A---B---C---D        (<-- old history's still there, nothing in your repo refers to it)
 \
  C'--D'             master
```

---

If communication isn't a problem, this is by far the best way to deal with slips.  Do the rebase, force-push the new history, and have everyone refetch.  If they've based work on the abandoned history they'll have to rebase too, but:

if nobody has based any work on the abandoned history, you're done.

Answer (score 1):

if it looks like a>b>c>d and you want to get rid of the last 2 commits,
just use :

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

and then

```
git push --force
```

another option is to use :

```
git reflog
```

which will show a list of changes made to the repository.

followed by

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{n}
git push --force
```

where n was the last commit you need in the branch.
another option is to use

```
git revert c d
git push --force
```