# Git undo changes by merge

Tags: git

I rolled my local repo back to a commit and then made some local changes. Now I wanted to update (simply overwrite) the remote with my local repo. But when I did a git pull, the terminal showed bunch of conflicts. I don't want the remote changes, I just want my local files to be committed.

I read somewhere to do

```
git checkout --ours
```

I ran it like

```
 git checkout --ours .
```

But after running the command when I did `git status` It showed the previous state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you want to overwrite your remote branch with whatever is there in the local branch.

This can be achieved with using the `-f` force option, or with `--force-with-lease` option in the git push command.
Get your local branch in the state you want and do:

```
git push -f origin <remoteBranch>
```

**Be careful though**
, this action has consequences, I highly recommend reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10510482/1695393

Also, when you perform `git pull`, git would try to merge remote and local branch, which would undo your work of preparing the local branch. Since you want to "overwrite" remote, I would advise to skip pulling.

Answer (score 0):

if you're still in this unclean state right now, you might want to do a `git reset --hard` to reset your local repository to the state it was in before your last pull that caused this.

Comment: Then what ? I mean how to commit my local changes?

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout --ours` just supports to checkout one file. So you type `git checkout --ours .` it will not work as you expect.

So in this case, you have to run `git checkout --ours [path_to_your_conflict_file]`

If you have too many conflicted files, you can run the command below:

```
for f in `git ls-files -m`;do git checkout --ours $f; done;
```

Comment: For further details, you can refer to my post: https://sonnguyen.ws/git-keep-files-merge-conflict/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to keep the history in the remote repo? Has anyone else pulled from it? If the answer to both these questions is "no", then you probably just want to get rid of the conflicts and force push.

```
git reset --hard <commit to keep>
git push --force origin <remote branch>
```

If you do want to keep the history in the remote repo and/or somebody has pulled, you can do this:

```
git reset --hard origin/<remote branch> # Erase changes (conflicts) in your working copy
git reset --soft <commit to keep>
git commit --all --message "Commit message with reason for restoring" 
git push
```

As @dubes writes, beware of the possible negative consequences of force pushing.