# How to Remove Git repository and push new one

Tags: git, github, repository, push, git-push

how can I Clear repository and push new one instead of it .

I have project with size more than 2GB , I checked `.git` folder and it's size is 1.5GB , I try to delete `.git` folder after that I did `git init` and force push project , but remote repository size not changed , my steps :

```
git init
git add . 
git commit -m "First Push"
git remote add origin http://Url_here
git push -f origin master
```

how to replace repository content ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few options:

- Go to the server repository, delete the old repo and create a new one.
  In the current repo push the new branches
- Create a new `orphan` branch and then push it.
  Now on your server run `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` to clean all the old commits
- Use `filter branch` to clean all the old content
- Use `rebase -i` and squash all your commits into one then push it
- Use `git subtree' split to create a new project from the existing code.Similar to`git filter-tree` which in your with the right code will produce the same results.

Comment: Can I change content by force push to the same repository ?
I did it befor and done , but now cannot clean the repository !

Comment: You can and then execute a git GC to clean old unrefered content

Comment: after force push to the repository run (git GC) ?
I will try it

Comment: Yep. `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` will clean all the content which is not in any commit. but if you have branches you will have to push each branch (force push)

Comment: I apply it , but Repository size not decreazed !
Does that decrease Repo size ?

Comment: Why wont you simply delete the old repo by deleting the .git folder on the remote server and then do a `git init --bare`. now push your branches to it and check the size.

Comment: Here you can read about more advanced options how to fix your branches. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset-old-commit/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 12):

log in as root remove *.git*

`sudo rm -R .git`

Log in as correct user

```
git init
git remote add origin https://[name]@bitbucket.org/frankdesign/[new-repo].git
git add .
git commit -m "new clean repo"
git push --force origin master
```

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work. The old commits are still on the server.

Answer (score 0):

See [Force "git push" to overwrite remote files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-push-to-overwrite-remote-files)

I think you are adding the origin master to your push force, so you are not overwriting everything...

`git push -f`

But this is replacing everything in the repository....

Comment: It will not work. the content will still be in the repo. it will not be cleaned !!!

Comment: yep you are right, forgot that the git was inited, so lost the connections to the repo...