# github : remove everything and start afresh

Tags: git, github

How can i remove all data/branches used and each and everything in my git.
i have set my default branch to master but while coding using command git status still shows branch A.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force "git push" to overwrite remote files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-push-to-overwrite-remote-files)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to force push (see comment) and possibly delete all remote branches as well (other than master).

You can delete all remote branches with something like this:

`git branch | grep -v 'master$'| xargs git push --delete`

Are you *sure* you want to do this, though? It sounds a lot like you just want to return to master, in which case: `git checkout master`