# Completely erase pushed commits

Tags: git

I have a repository with about 16 commits, all pushed to the remote server, all only committed on the master branch.

I want the last 3 commits completely erased as if they never happened, so that someone looking at the repo will only see the first 13. 
I don't even want to know about the last three.

How do I do this? I see so many different answers for different situations. I just need help for this specific scenario.

Comment: You can force push:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-push-to-overwrite-remote-files

Comment: You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete commits from a branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git)

Comment: You should probably revert those 3 commits.  If you nuke them and force push, then anyone else using the branch will certainly know something is awry.

Comment: Will a `git reset --hard` leave a history of those commits? @DonaldShahini @Rumid

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen won't that still show the history of the commits? I'm the only one working on this repo

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is definitely not what the OP is asking about. History rewriting is dangerous but it is sometimes necessary. That said, you *should* be extra-sure that really is what you want. Why do you want to completely erase those commits?

Comment: @DanielH This is why I am suggesting _not_ to rewrite history, and to instead use `git revert`.  Anyway, in either case if the branch be already shared others would know that something has happened.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

you will delete  the 3 last commits, but since you have already pushed it to remote, you will need to force push it.

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

Be aware that if others have already pulled these commits, when they pull again the deleted commits will get merged and might be pushed back.

As a side note, `git revert` is usually the best way to go since it will not rewrite history, avoiding possible complications.