# Why I can't push to github from Xcode 9.3?

Tags: xcode, git, github

[image]

I just update from xcode 9.2 to xcode 9.3, but when I try to push to my existing github project, it shows an alert like that? the alert is

> The local repository is out of date. make sure all changes have been
>   pulled from the remote repository and try again

I just add existing remote repository like the picture below, and then copy paste the link
[image]

[image]

and this is the git status from the command line
[image]

what went wrong in here?

Comment: use command line stash your changes first then take the pull request then commit and then push your code, *local repository is out of date* means you are lagging behind from the master branch and on top of that you're pushing your code to master..

Comment: In command line run ~> git status ; then check what has happened actually, if theres a pull request STASH your changes, ~> git stash save;  then type in git pull ; after taking the pull type in ~> git stash pop; then add your files which are to be committed and and to be pushed , by ~> git add *Files* then ~> git commit ; then ~> git push origin master

Comment: I really don't understand this, but this is my git status https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7uPR.png , it is said nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: read the link's answer properly, it'll help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10510482/4598318 , Also after reading if the problem still persists then comment again.

Comment: try this command  and check  remote url  - > " git remote get-url --all origin  "
if it is correct  remote url using command  -> "git add " -> "git commit -m " -> "git push origin <master>" 
if it is not correct  git remote set-url

Comment: it is said "Nothing specified, nothing added.
Maybe you wanted to say 'git add .'?" when I type "git add"