# Git how to reset remote

Tags: git

I have a repository with a branch called "develop". Both origin and local are the same. Now I want to reset the last commit(s). I do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This does what I want locally. How can I sync these changes to the remote repository? When I try to push now I get the error that my remote is X commits ahead.

```
git reset origin/develop --hard HEAD^
```

does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force "git push" to overwrite remote files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-push-to-overwrite-remote-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type command like as below

```
1: git reset --hard  HEAD^
2: git push -f origin develop
```

Comment: As a bonus, you might want to replace `-f` with `--force-with-lease` (see [why](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---force-with-leaseltrefnamegt))