# Get out of conflict between local and remote branch

Tags: git

What I did:

- Refactored a lot on the branch I’m working on, committed, and pushed the branch to my remote repo.
- Realized the refactoring was actually a bad decision, and used git reset --hard to go back to the commit before (not realizing this was probably the wrong way to go, since I had already pushed).
- Made some other changes, committed them, and tried to push them, which was rejected because my local branch “is behind”.

I tried to use git revert on my unwanted refactoring-commit, but eventually just got back to the sames state.

The remote repo is just something I have for personal backup purposes, and it doesn’t matter if it winds up with an abandoned branch or something. All I want is to get back to a state where I can work on the branch the way it looks locally, and push it to the remote. How do I get there in a smooth way? Should I make what I have locally into a different branch, perhaps?

Comment: Use git push with `--force` option, it will make remote branch looks the same as local.

Comment: Oh, that simple… Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force "git push" to overwrite remote files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-push-to-overwrite-remote-files) Or [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge/18135171)

Comment: @IMSoP The answers in those questions are the same as for mine, but it isn’t clear to me whether the context of the questions are exactly the same.

Comment: @njlarsson The context, in a nutshell, is "I have one version of history on a remote server, and a different version locally; how do I make the local one overwrite the remote one".

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, that’s my context, but reading the other questions, I would not have understood that they were about that same context.