# remove git commit from github committed by another person

Tags: git, github

I have a clean local repos with my last commit **10001**, and I have pushed it to the github remote repos. But a colleague has pushed two more commits after mine, commit **10002** and **10003** . So the remote repos is two commits ahead of mine.
How can I remove those two commits from the remote repos so that my last commit is the last one also in the remote repos?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to overwrite those commits on the branch you can do `git push --force` to force your history to overwrite the remote history. This will completely remove your colleagues commits though so make sure this is what you want to do.

You might need to do `git push - - force <remote> <branch>` if you're not tracking the remote branch.

Possible duplicate of [Overriding remote git repository with my repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310208/overriding-remote-git-repository-with-my-repository)