# Git: How to make local unchanged files go back to online repo where they were accidentally deleted?

Tags: git, github

Ok, so the online repo accidentally deleted a bunch of files when an uneeded branch was deleted.  I have all the files locally, but they're unchanged, so it doesn't want to add or commit them back.  I reset the HEAD to get rid of the out of sync messages, but if I do a git pull from master, it wants to delete a bunch of local stuff that I need.

So basically, I want to force it to take all my local files, unchanged or not, and push them to the online master repo.

I don't need to worry about messing up anyone else.  I'm working on this project alone.

Comment: If the files you want to save are in a commit, let's say on master branch, you can `push -f` to master. Thus, the commit with the files you want to save will end up on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a similar case to [Overriding remote git repository with my repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310208/overriding-remote-git-repository-with-my-repository) I believe a `git push -f <remote> <branch>` would work. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10510482/13186719) post for additional considerations